# SPListItem update yields ItemUpdated/ing Numbering Scheme not found

Tags: 2007, splistitem, updatelistitems

I've written a console app that searches items in a SP document library (MOSS 2007) for a specific condition and updates the value in a column for each item that meets the criterion. I run the console app as a domain/SP admin and on the front-end SP server, so there is no question of security, rights, etc. The code in question is as follows:

```
 item["some column"] = "some value";
 item.Update();
```

In my test environment, the above code works perfectly. But in production, it sometimes appears to work properly but more frequently spits out extra output that looks something like this:

```
1 2/19/2012 10:23:47 AM ItemUpdating http://server/sites/web/Shared Documents/Document01.pdf > http://server/sites/web/Shared Documents/Document01.pdf
1 2/19/2012 10:23:47 AM ItemUpdating SetID: Key=shared documents/Document01.pdf value=
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <udn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <id>0002871</id>
        <time>634652438271779415</time>
        <move>false</move>
        <movefinished>false</movefinished>
    </udn>
10 2/19/2012 10:23:47 AM ItemUpdated SetValue: 0002326
```

Examining the item's column value, I can see the column value has been updated. But all this output is making me wonder if there are any adverse side effects.

Comment: I am yet to get to the bottom of this problem, but it appears the extraneous log was due to an list item event receiver implemented on the document library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my case is concerned, this turned out to be unrelated to my customization, and was caused by another of the document library's event receivers.